# jQuery validation plugin - how to style 1 validation message differently to others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a form that is being validated with the jQuery validation plugin successfully.
Messages are displayed in the correct position and in the correct situations.

So far, so good.

I have 1 field that is being validated correctly, but I need to position that 1 validation message differently to the others. With 2 inputs next to each other, I want the validation to appear under them both (ie under the block that wraps them both) rather than to the right per individual inputs.

The validation on these 2 inputs are dependent on each other, ie at least one must have input. The validation rule works, it's just the positioning I'm struggling with.

I'm using the following validation syntax:

```
$('#formId').validate({
          rules: {
          },
          messages : {
          }
}
```

In my HTML I have created a label specifically for the (radio) field I am trying to customise:

```
   <label for="radioName" id="radioNameId-invalid" class="error"">Some error message</label>
```

I tried adding content to the 'showErrors' function of validate, which works, but seemingly then doesn't show any of the other validation messages in my page.

```
    showErrors: function(errors) {
                        var collectionMethodError = errors['collectionMethod'];
                        if(collectionMethodError) {
                            $('#radioNameId-invalid').text(errorString);
                            $('#radioNameId-invalid').css("display","block");

                        }
                    }
```

I want to enable this error AND then allow validator to continue to do its default behaviour for other fields.

If I remove the showErrors function, the other validation messages are displayed but not my custom one.

How can I get both behaviours?

Comment: can you put in a fiddle please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the errorPlacement function instead of the showErrors function:

```
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element){
                        $(error).insertAfter(element);

                        // special case for display
                        if($(element).attr("name")=="radioName") {
                            $(error).insertAfter("#anElement"));
                            $("label[for=radioName].error").attr("id","invalid-radio-message");
                        }
                    }
```

So in short I'm adding an ID to a label that validation plugin adds, then styling to that ID in my css.

That seems to do what I was trying to do. Now to workout the re-hiding of the message!